# Big O as an exponent on both sides?

Tags: math, big-o

Lets say we have an expression like

```
2f(n) = O(2g(n))
```

I don't understand the expression. I know that what `f(n) = O(n)` is. It basically means that the left side is asymptotically bounded above at `O(n)`.
O being the Big O notation.

Comment: Then, in this case, 2^f(n) is bounded by the big-O expression.

Comment: Are you wondering how to solve the Big O for `f(n)` or are you confused what this means for `2^f(n)`?

Comment: Think of it as `f'(n) = O(g'(n))` where `f'(n) = 2^f(n)` and `g'(n)= 2^g(n)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically it means `2g(n)` is an asymptotic upper bound for `2f(n)`.

Now one can think this is the same as `f(n) ∈ O(g(n))`, but this is only correct in one direction.

```
2f(n) ∈ O(2g(n))      ⇒      f(n) ∈ O(g(n))
```

But the other way around is not correct.

E.g.:
`f(n) = 2n`, `g(n) = n` so
`2n ∈ O(n)` holds, but `22n = 4n ∉ O(2n)`.